# UserForm check the existing list before creating new data VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a userform with inputs: Name (TextBox1), Surname (TextBox2), Date of birth (TextBox3) and 1 output which would basically be their ID (goes from 1 to inf). What bothers me is that I want to code that if lets say Name and Surname already exists in database, msg will popup and form will reset else everything will be put to the table. I kind of managed to do that. Problem is now if I do put name and surname that already exists it wont input it in the table and it will show the message, but even if it doesn't exists the message will still pop up but it will input it in the table. This is the code:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet2
    Dim a As Integer
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    iRow = ws.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    If Not (TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "") Then
        With ws
            Label1.Caption = iRow - 1
                For a = 1 To iRow
                    If (ws.Cells(a, 2).Value = TextBox1.Value And ws.Cells(a, 3).Value = TextBox2.Value) Then
                        MsgBox "Values you entered already exists!"
                        Call Reset
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                        .Range("A" & iRow).Value = Label1.Caption
                        .Range("B" & iRow).Value = TextBox1.Value
                        .Range("C" & iRow).Value = TextBox2.Value
                        .Range("D" & iRow).Value = TextBox3.Value
                    End If
                Next a
         End With
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are checking down to the row where the new record is inserted. So for every row that does not match the new record is inserted at iRow. When the loop gets to the end it checks iRow, matches and shows the message. Separate code into 2 steps, first check then update or reset.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long, r As Long, bExists As Boolean
    Set ws = Sheet2
    iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' check exists
    For r = 1 To iRow
        If (ws.Cells(r, 2).Value = TextBox1.Value) _
            And (ws.Cells(r, 3).Value = TextBox2.Value) Then
            bExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
 
    ' update sheet
    If bExists Then
        MsgBox "Values you entered already exists!"
        Call Reset
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Label1.Caption = iRow
        iRow = iRow + 1
        With ws
            .Range("A" & iRow).Value = Label1.Caption
            .Range("B" & iRow).Value = TextBox1.Value
            .Range("C" & iRow).Value = TextBox2.Value
            .Range("D" & iRow).Value = TextBox3.Value
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```